# Laser diode help?

Tags: diodes, laser, pinout

I recently took apart an old DVD player, for the laser diodes, but instead I found some strange looking components with many pins.
Please help me find out what they’re are and the pinouts[image][image]

Comment: Btw the 2 modules aren’t connected

Comment: They are the CD/DVD optical pickup modules. Without a datasheet and a whole bunch of electronics, there's nearly nothing you can do with these. Salvaging the laser diode isn't worth it when you can buy one complete with wires from Ebay for 1 Euro from China including shipment.

Comment: shouldn’t one of the modules be the actual laser diode because there was nothing else in the whole scanning unit?

Comment: While you are buying one from ebay, get a better camera (although "ebay" and "better" are an oxymoron)

Comment: I do have a good cam, I just could not get it to focus on the small features, I’ve done it before it just takes FOREVER!

Answer (score 1):

As exciting as these are, @Bimpelrekkie is right. They are useless without the support electronics, and that is radically different for each module.

Just buy a new laser module with known specs and connections.